# Bootstrap displays tablet version on IE8

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-8, twitter-bootstrap-3

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<link href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
</head>

<body>
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="form">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" placeholder="Email" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Sign in</button>
          </form>
        </div><!--/.navbar-collapse -->
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Main jumbotron for a primary marketing message or call to action -->
    <div class="jumbotron">
      <div class="container">
        <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
        <p>This is a template for a simple marketing or informational website. </p>
        <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" role="button">Learn more &raquo;</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
      <!-- Example row of columns -->
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <h2>Heading</h2>
          <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus.  </p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <h2>Heading</h2>
          <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. </p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
       </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <h2>Heading</h2>
          <p>Donec sed odio dui. </p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <hr>

      <footer>
        <p>&copy; Company 2014</p>
      </footer>
    </div> <!-- /container -->


<!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster --> 
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the HTML code. Have included the respond.js too. But still the site is displayed as the mobile version in ie8.

Am using Bootstrap version 3.1.1. The strange thing is i have built a site with similar version which doesnt have this problem. Please suggest a solution

Comment: Just a guess: Bootstrap 3 is mobile first and respond.js is wrapped in the conditional CSS `<!--[if lt IE 9]>`, meaning the responsive code is only getting loaded in IE9?

Comment: lt (less than) selects all ie version below 9. but i did test by removing the comments but still same result.

Comment: Hit F12 to open your dev tools. Click on the Network tab, click Start Capturing, and then reload your page. Take note of any 404s.

Comment: I finally got it working. My bad i didn't test it using a local server. any idea why was it not working while running as a local file.?

Comment: Some browsers won't let respond.js run from a file:// url due to security restrictions, best to run it form a local webserver

Comment: The Respond.js `file://` issue is mentioned in the docs: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#support-ie8-respondjs

Comment: yes just saw the docs.could have read it first wasted a lot of time.  thanks for the responses..

Answer (score 0):

Put respond.js file into the project folder.

```
  https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js
```

Comment: please check it on live server

Comment: It worked for me on local server but not as a local file. I mentioned it on my previous comments.